# Vuejs3, pinia | get an item from array

Tags: python, mysql, vuejs3, pinia

'Hope someone can help me. I'm studying Vue, pinia... even javascript...
An array of data comes from mySQL database through python backend, pinia and I want to access to an item in the array...

```
<script setup>
    import { computed, ref }from 'vue'
    import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
    import { useBaseStore } from '../stores/base'
    
    const { area }  = storeToRefs(useBaseStore())
    const { fetchArea } = useBaseStore()
    
    fetchArea()
    
    const areaName = computed(() => {
        return area
    })
</script>

 <template>
    <div>{{ areaName }}</div>
 </template>
```

and it shows

```
{ "area": [ { "id": 1, "name": "AFRICA" }, { "id": 2, "name": "CARRIBEAN" }, { "id": 3, "name": "CENTRAL AMERICA" }, { "id": 4, "name": "SOUTH EAST ASIA" }, { "id": 5, "name": "NORTH AMERICA" }, { "id": 6, "name": "SOUTH AMERICA" }, { "id": 7, "name": "MIDDLE EAST" }, { "id": 8, "name": "ASIA" }, { "id": 9, "name": "INDIA" } ], "status": "success" }
```

I want to show 'if id === 1', show name (in this case 'AFRICA') at {{ areaName }},
please advise me how? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong: you simply want to display the name in the template based on the id condition. If that's the case, then we can use [template syntax and combine it with JavaScript expressions](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#using-javascript-expressions) to render the value:

```html
<template>
    <div> {{ areaName.area.find(({id}) => id === 1 ).name }} </div>
</template>
```

To break it down:

- `areaName.area` gets the value of `area` property: `[ { "id": 1, "name": "AFRICA" }, ...]`
- [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) retrieves the first array element that satisfies the condition declared. In this case: `id === 1`. Note that we're also [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#syntax) the element to access the `id` property directly
- `.name` accesses the property value of the element's `name` property

Combining all of these will display "AFRICA" in `<div>`. Since the data is retrieved from your python backend, we can also add a condition to check if areaName has the property `area`:

```js
'area' in areaName ? areaName.area.find(({id}) => id === 1 ).name : ''
```

This way if the backend doesn't return data, then we won't trigger any `TypeError`s.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, Christopher. 
I tried and got "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')"... 
I've tried "find" "forEach" javescript expressions... but always give me the same error like this.
And what I want to do is to destructure an element within <script setup>...</script> and display the result. Probably my question is "how to destructure an element in an array?"

Thanks again and Happy 4th of July!!

Comment: @beable You encountered `TypeError` because the `areaName` is empty.  I added a condition to make sure that `areaName` has the property `area` before running `find()`. Also, I recommend you move your `fetchArea()` inside a [onBeforeMount()](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onbeforemount) hook like so: `onBeforeMount(async()=> await fetchArea())`. That way, we ensure that the data is retrieved first before loading the template.